# Batch only show directorys and their subdirectorys

Tags: batch-file

I am having an question
How can i loop through an folder and only show folders and their subfolders without the full path.

example
if i use dir /b /s /ad
i will see e:\Mainfolder\Folder1\Subfolder

And i only whant to see
Folder1\Subfolder

the reason i want it is so i can put it inside an txt field and then with another loop check if the folder/subfolder exist somewhere else if not then it needs to create it.

With kind regards,

Thomas de Vries

Comment: is the structure consistent? or is it possible for it to be `e:\MainFolder\Folder1\Subfolder\SubSubfolder\etc\`

Comment: The structure could change cause the person can Add or Delete an directory and its sub directory.

Comment: How do you know the part of the path you want to eliminate? It is always `"e:\Mainfolder"`? It is the current dir?

Comment: Yes this part needs to be replaced. e:\Mainfolder

so it will only displays subfolder\subsubfolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "startingFolder=%cd%"

    :: Determine the length of the starting path to remove
    :: it from output 
    for /d %%a in ("%startingFolder%\"
    ) do for /f "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=:" %%b in (
        '(echo(%%~fa^&echo(^)^|findstr /o "^"'
    ) do set /a "cutPoint=%%b-3"

    :: Recurse folders from starting point and echo the 
    :: full path without the starting folder
    for /r "%startingFolder%" /d %%a in (*) do (
        set "line=%%a"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!line:~%cutPoint%!
        endlocal
    )
```

This will recurse over the tree structure, starting at the indicated folder (change `startingFolder` variable to what you need). For each folder found its relative path is echoed to console. Redirect output of batch to generate the required .txt file

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad') do (
   set "name=%%a"
   echo !name:*e:\Mainfolder\=!
)
```